# Vimeo API - Get public video details using access token

Tags: get, access-token, vimeo-api

I need to get public information about Vimeo Video. I want to use the vimeo-php code from Vimeo, I have created my App, with credentials and access-token, but I cannot find a way to use them.

When I ask for:
    https://api.vimeo.com/videos/{video_id}/access_token={access_token}

I got the error: you must provide an authenticated access token.

Someone can explain me how to make a call correctly?

Answer (score 1):

When you read the documentation notice you have to add the Authorization header to your request. Please read https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication#making-requests.

Answer (score 1):

You can get video using retrofit too.

```
String BASE_URL = "https://api.vimeo.com/";//For Retrofit client object

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
```

---

```
@GET("/videos/{videoId}")
Call<MyVideoResponse> getPrivateVimeoVideo(@HeaderMap Map<String, String> 
headers, @Path("videoId") String videoId);
```

---

Then you can call like this...

```
String accessToken = "1a1e1ec3***************";
Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
headers.put("Accept", "application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.2");
String videoId = "309065...";`enter code here`
RetrofitClient.create(ApiInterface.class).getPrivateVimeoVideo(headers, 
videoId).enqueue(new CallBack<MyVideoResponse>(){...........}
```